# Mysql returns different amount of rows

Tags: mysql

If I run `SELECT * FROM table;` on one of my tables, I get **87709** rows.

If I instead run `SELECT * FROM table WHERE isDeleted = 0 OR isDeleted = 1;` on the same table, I get **87686** rows.

*isDeleted* only has the values of 0 or 1, which I have confirmed with `SELECT DISTINCT isDeleted FROM table;`

Where have the 23 missing rows gone?

---

ANSWER:

Thx [Roland Aaronson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2823719/ronald-aaronson) for pointing out that phpMyAdmins "count" is not as accurate as `COUNT(*)`.

Did `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table;` and `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE isDeleted = 0 OR isDeleted = 1;` which gave the same amount of rows! *YAY*

Comment: you only get 2 rows returned when 'SELECT DISTINCT isDeleted FROM table;' ?

Comment: @P.Salmon yes, 0 and 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT isDeleted, COUNT(*) from table GROUP BY isDeleted;
```

If you want to get an accurate count and all the distinct values. I am guessing your "count" might be what something like phpMyAdmin is showing, which may not be accurate.

Comment: you were right! The "count" shown by phpMyAdmin is not as accurate as ```COUNT(*)```

Answer (score 1):

run this query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE isDeleted ISNULL`, then you will rows with the null. If it has 23 rows, that's where the problem lies

Comment: Maybe. What if  `isDeleted` is nullable and has a value of `NULL`?

Comment: Then he will see it in the results, I also had the same suspision. If it is indeed null, the column needs to be altered to be made not nullable

Comment: **No!** NULL never compares equal or not equal to 0 or 1 or any value, not even NULL.

Comment: Oh, just checked that. You are right. updating my answer

Comment: 'IS NULL' not 'ISNULL'. But that has already been offered as an answer.

Comment: Ah, I see your answer is more comprehensive. Also ISNULL works in postgres, I thought it would work with mysql

Comment: `ISNULL` is a function. for example,  `... WHERE ISNULL(expr)`, that returns 0 or 1 if `expr` is NULL or not. So, you would have needed `... WHERE ISNULL(isDeleted)`

Comment: I know that ISNULL is a function in mysql, in postgres ISNULL is a nonstandard construct for IS NULL

Comment: ```isDeleted``` does not have the value of ```NULL```. Just to be sure, I double checked with ```SELECT * FROM table WHERE isDeleted IS NULL;```

Answer (score -1):

You could confirm the values is not null by

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE isDeleted IS NOT NULL

Comment: If NULL does not show up on `SELECT DISTINCT ...`, it will not show up here either.